# Modeling of many small objects

Tags: modeling

How can you create a lot of such small cubes on the handle? Or I have to create thousands of objects and place them. enter image description here

At first I wanted to make all the cups on the model of the handle itself, but I think this is not the best idea.[image]

Comment: Hello, do you need them to be modeled for real or can't it be faked with height map or normal map?

Comment: @moonboots hi, I recently started studying modeling, is it possible to achieve such an effect using a normal map?

Comment: of course, except you won't see any 3D bumps like the ones we see on the side

Comment: @moonboots Okay thanks, I'll try to do it.

Comment: Hi Please use a title that reflects the content of the question. It should be descriptive but succinct, unique and identifying, summarizing the issue so that users can at a glance understand what your post is about. Use the [edit] link below your post and avoid anything not strictly essential to the post. Remember, your title is the first thing potential visitors will see, and makes your question findable for future users. See ["*What is the problem with posting an image or link and asking “How do I do this?"*"](https://blender.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2449)

Comment: @КириллБелов make one small cube approximately size like in picture and use array modifier just increase numbers on x and y and rotate it so it matches position like on picture 1 min job

Comment: https://i.stack.imgur.com/SJCvC.png

Comment: @SlobodanVidovic This is really useful, especially in conjunction with curves. Thank you.